# Background Job (launched with '&') Stops On Logout

Tags: bash

I am using AWS to setup a Node.JS server.  I launch node in the background by the following command:

```
node server.js &
```

However, when I log out, the process ends.  From my previous 'nix experience, I was under the impression it should stay running.  What am I doing wrong?  How to keep the process alive even after terminal logs out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you start with `&`, the process is a child of your shell, e.g., `bash`. When you log out, bash terminates, together with its children. If you want to have it running after logout, a different process has to start it. For example, for processes started at runtime, try writing an rc script and put its call into /etc/rc.local

Comment: or run the command in screen

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, if not wanting to use rc.scripts, just launch it from any shell script with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line.  this automatically causes it to start under separate process